# How to create ARFF file for 2D data points?

Tags: classification, weka, nearest-neighbor

I want to create an ARFF dataset for WEKA and use `Nearest Neighbors` classifier on it. My data are 2D points with `X` and `Y` coordinates and I'll use Euclidean distance to find the neighbors.

Is this the correct format?

```
@RELATION name

@ATTRIBUTE X       NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Y       NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE class   {classy,classless}

@DATA
0,4,classy
0,6,classy
1,3,classless
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for a yes or no answer?  That is the correct format for an ARFF file with two numeric attributes and a binary class. This link provides lots of details on the ARFF format http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html.

Comment: I was wondering if Euclidean distance works with this format or not?

Comment: Euclidean distance works with this format. However you may want to use *consine similarity* instead, in case that for you, points (1,2) and (100,200) should be considered very similar or close, because of proportions.

WEKA's Nearest Neighbors algorithms are diverse. You can find them under `weka.classifiers.lazy`. The most typical one, IBk, does not use the Euclidean Distance if, as stated in the doc, it follows the classic Aha *et al.* paper. The other ones do not use the Euclidean Distance either (according to the doc).